# CSS easy: How can I add margin to my div´s without breaking the lines

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, margin, line-breaks

I cannot add margin without breaking the line. I found a way to adjust the media queries, but my columns are not aligned on the right side when I reach a certain breakpoint:

[image]

I cannot use flow as I am in an assignment on coursera. I have to use media queries + float + margins

```
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}

p {
    margin-top: -18px;
}

p.meat {
   float: right;
   top: 0;
   width: 100px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: -32px -3px 0px;
   border: 3px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 125%;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: #FFB6C1;
}

section {}

div {}

div#container {
  font-family: Arial;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Desktop*/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: left;
  }

  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px;
  }
}

/*Tablet*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.99px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> Mod2_Solution

<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<p> Chicken </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua consequat.
</p>

<section>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <p class="meat"> Beef </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
    <p class="meat"> Pork </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua consequat.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't even render like what your screenshot shows. Why is the Chicken part not wrapped into the same kind of structure in the HTML, as the other two? And _what_ do you even need to add a margin to here?

Comment: Doing such layouts using `float` is really quite the antiquated approach - you should go look into `flexbox`.

Comment: @CBroe My bad, I did not copy the first part of the HTML code "Chicken" is wrapped in the following snippet:

<div id="container" class="row">
 <section>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"> 
   <p class="meat"> Chicken </p>

I would like to use flex box but the requirement in this assignment is not to use it... Is there any way to solve it without flexbox?

Comment: a) fix the example in the question then, please, instead of just telling us in comments. b) what about the question I asked you? It is still unclear what the issue is even supposed to be, what margin you need to add where, and why.

Answer (score 0):

How about some flex instead of float?

```css
.box
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.text
{
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.caption
{
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
          </div>
          <div class="caption">
            Pork
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```